# 'Locking' intervals in interval determination

Tags: qgis

Working with graduated maps in Qgis 2.8 I'd like to lock a certain interval value while letting Qgis determine the rest - in relation to eg. missing values.

I know how to work with queries, but this makes Qgis not display certain values at all, where as i would like for it to display these values but disregard them in interval determination. Query filtering furthermore requires manual addition of the empty interval class whereas the method I'm looking for automates this by "always" having the class interval locked.

Comment: Can you make an example clarifying the problem?

Comment: Say i have some data in the range of [100;200] and one missing value of 0. By default, Qgis will interpret the 0 as relevant, and include it in the resulting intervals making the 1st interval "wrong" (from say 0-100). I was wondering if you could tell Qgis to have a "locked" interval from [0-0] denoted "missing" (meaning 1st relevant interval would be 100-150), thus not needing to remove the observation  and manually adding an interval

Comment: This post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128358/symbolising-null-features-in-graduated-symbology partially covers the subject, in a somehow different manner though. I would still, if someone knows how, a solution like mine.

Comment: Null values is not available for integers and graduated styling. I can only think of making your own null value like a large number above your dataset like 99999999 with the field calculator and then manually delete the last interval.

Comment: This will however give me the exact same result - only in the other end. In your example, my question is whether Qgis can handle a fixed interval 99999999, and not regard this data value in any other intervals.

Comment: No not in graduated styles.