# How to display missing objects in QGIS 2.8.2 cartogram?

Tags: qgis, cartogram

I've just created cartogram using styles/graduated symbol. But there are some missing elements on the map. Objects without data in attribute table are not present on the map (NULL in corresponding column in Attibute table). I was able to show such objects on the map using 0.0-0.0 interval in previous versions of QGIS. It does nothing now, just showing objects with 0 value but NULL objects are still missing. How to display them to make my map complete?

> Grey countries with 0 value, white spaces (e.g. South Sudan) while
>   NULL is in the column.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Symbolising null features in graduated symbology](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128358/symbolising-null-features-in-graduated-symbology)

Comment: Yes, there is the same problem. But it seems like a bug or missing important feature in newer QGIS :( I have examine which QGIS version did it correct...